# To count the number of letters in a word and no of words in a sentence

Tags: c

I am just trying to experiment with counting the number of letters in a word.To distinguish between words in a string I am checking for blank spaces.If it encounters blank space then it is one word and it has respective letters.
For example "Hello World". So the output is supposed to be like

```
o/p
Hello has 5 letters
World has 5 letter
```

But when I am trying to write the code I am getting Segmentation fault. Below is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main(void) {

    int nc = 0;
    int word = 0;

    char str[] = "This test";
    int len = strlen(str);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        ++nc;
        if(isspace(str)){        
             ++word;   
        }

    }

    printf("%d\n",nc);

}
```

Comment: Look at `isspace(str)`. I think u meant `str[i]`

Comment: `isspace(str)`? this looks bad.... Why don't you make use of `i`? :-)

Comment: also, isn't `isspace()` needs `#include <ctype.h>`?

Comment: You might want to read e.g. [this `isspace` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
   if(isspace(str[i]))
   {
       ++word;
       continue;
   }
  ++nc;
}

if(len>0) word++;

printf("%d %d\n",nc, word);
```

Comment: The number of 'words' is not defined as "the number of spaces + 1".

Comment: Number of word is (number of spaces + 1). Is not it?

Comment: No. `" counterexample"`, `" counter example "`, `"counter ###  example"` (where `#` is to represent a space). No sweat though, it's a minor thing, as your code corrects what the OP did wrong.

Comment: You are right.. But I think he was thinking only about positive part. "counter example"

Answer (score 2):

Add `#include <ctype.h>` in the beginning to get the prototype of `isspace()`, and

```
if(isspace(str))
```

should be

```
if(isspace(str[i]))
```

Comment: hi timrau thanks for the quick reply.It is working now. But could you please tell me what went wrong there.

Answer (score 2):

First, add `#include <ctype.h>` in your code.

Next, [`isspace()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isspace) intakes one `int` argument and checks the input [in terms of ASCII value] to be

> white-space characters. In the "C" and "POSIX" locales, these are: space, form-feed ('\f'), newline ('\n'), carriage return ('\r'), horizontal tab ('\t'), and vertical tab ('\v').

So, you need to provide the elements of the array `str` one-by-one to `isspace()`. For that, you need to change your code to

```
if(isspace(str[i]))
```

which will give non-zero value if `str[i]` is a white-space character.

Also, to match your required output [as mentioned in the question], you need to make use of the intermediate values of `str[i]` and reset `nc` after every `TRUE` value of `isspace()`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the condition like this.

```
 if(isspace(str[i]))
```

Because isspace is `int isspace(int c);`

Answer (score 0):

```
int isspace(int c);
```

This is the prototype of `isspace()` function.

You need to pass the the value which you want to check like:

```
isspace(str[i]);
```

not the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
int len = strlen(str);    //len will be number of letters
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    if(isspace(str[i]))       
         ++word;   
}

if(len){
//if you dont want to count space letters then write
//len -= word; 
    word++;     //counting last word
}
printf("letters = %d, Words =%d", len,word);
```

As you are getting `len` it will give you number of letters so no need to count `nc`.